# Error while installing lamp-server

Tags: server, software-installation, lamp, locale, tasksel

I want to install `lamp-server` via `tasksel`. But when I enter the command:
`sudo tasksel install lamp-server` , I get error:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_PAPER = "fa_IR",
    LC_ADDRESS = "fa_IR",
    LC_MONETARY = "fa_IR",
    LC_NUMERIC = "fa_IR",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "fa_IR",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "fa_IR",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "fa_IR",
    LC_TIME = "fa_IR",
    LC_NAME = "fa_IR",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
tasksel: aptitude failed (100)
```

What should I do?

**UPDATE:** The output of `locale -a`:

```
C
C.UTF-8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
```

Comment: When you do `sudo tasksel`, what do you get?

Comment: @Mitch I see "software selection" page, and when I choose "Lamp Server", I get error again.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the output of the command `locale -a`

Comment: @Gunnar Hjalmarsson I edited question.

Comment: See that. Then you didn't run `sudo locale-gen fa_IR` as I suggested in my answer. I suggest that you do so.

Comment: @Gunnar Hjalmarsson I had run that command, but it didn't work. Then I tried Mitch's trick and this is why the output is en_US.utf8.
Finally I think the answer is: `sudo locale-get fa_IR` and `sudo apt-get update`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to generate the `fa_IR` locale:

```
sudo locale-gen fa_IR
```

Comment: I don't get that error with this command, But I can't install lamp-server yet. Now I get `tasksel: aptitude failed (100)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
export LANGUAGE=fa_IR
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=fa_IR
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Try doing this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo tasksel lamp-server
```

Comment: It didn't work. I get `tasksel: aptitude failed (100)`.

Comment: See added info in my answer.

Comment: error on this command: export LC_ALL=fa_IR. error: -bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (fa_IR)